# libtool failed with exit code 1 in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I compile my project, it shows this error:

> Libtool /Users/trinstanchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSSocial-dedmezxegpbuqnfkhmbfrvtphyas/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libiOSSocial.a normal i386
>       cd "/Users/trinstanchen/Downloads/iOSSocial-develop copy/iOSSocial"
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/trinstanchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSSocial-dedmezxegpbuqnfkhmbfrvtphyas/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/trinstanchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSSocial-dedmezxegpbuqnfkhmbfrvtphyas/Build/Intermediates/iOSSocial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSSocial.build/Objects-normal/i386/iOSSocial.LinkFileList -ObjC -fno-objc-arc -framework CoreGraphics -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/trinstanchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSSocial-dedmezxegpbuqnfkhmbfrvtphyas/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libiOSSocial.a
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `f' in: -fno-objc-arc
>   Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT]
>   Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table ] [-seg_addr_table_filename ] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

can anyone give me help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264379/unknown-option-character-f-in-fno-objc-arc

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have resolved it. You see, I remove "-fno-objc-arc" in 'Other Linker flags'